# Laura hire in apple?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Laura has applied for a job with Company A. As part of the hiring process, Company A will of course look at her grade in a Business class. If Laura gets an $A$, there is a $85\%$ chance that Company A will hire her. But if she does not get an $A$, there is only a $10\%$ chance that they will hire her. Laura's professor says that there is a $70\%$ chance that Laura will get an A in her Business class $90$.

What is the probability that Laura gets an A in Business class and also gets hired by Company A?

My answer is $= 0.952$ that is correct?

Comment: Is she trying to be hired by apple or is she trying to be hired by facebook?  Before math comprehension, reading comprehension should come first.

Comment: thats rigth!!! suppose apple.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at your answer?

Comment: I found P(H)=P(H|A) *P(A) +P(H|A')P(A') , then I need P(H intersection A), therefore I apply mult. rule and I have :P(h|a)=P(h intersection A)*P(h) /P(a).

Comment: Please explain "BUS 90 at SJSU". This is not common knowledge.

Comment: @barakmanos presumably it is the business class which the OP is enrolled in.  "Business 90."  It just gives flavor to the problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz: So "BUS 90" is the name of the class and "SJSU" is the name of the academic institution? Despite the flavor, this sentence is rather hard to read.

Comment: @Electro82: Please can you explain what the events H and A mean and edit your question to explain your reasoning and how you arrived at the answer.

Comment: The answer is 0.595, I use a wrong formula(equation).

P(h|a)=P(h intersection A) /P(a)

Thanks

Comment: A fascinating title; I won't dare to edit it into something boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your comment above. But you should explain your reasoning so that someone who is reading your answer can understand the steps that you took to arrive at that answer. For example, this is how I would write-up the solution:

Let $H$ be the event that Laura gets hired and $A$ be the event that she gets an A in class. Then from the definition of conditional probability we have,

\begin{eqnarray}
P(H|A) & = & \frac{P(H \cap A)}{P(A)} \\
\implies P(H \cap A) & = & P(H |A) P(A) \\
\implies P(H \cap A) &=& 0.85 \times 0.7 = 0.595 \textrm{ (Substituting the probabilities given in the question).}
\end{eqnarray}

So the probability that Laura gets an A in business class and also gets hired by the company is $59.5\%$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine 1000 "Laura"s.  70% of them, 700 "Laura"s, get an A.  85% of the 700 "Laura"s who get an A, .85(700)= 595, are hired by company A.  So 595 of the 1000 "Laura"s, 595/1000= 0.595 or 59.5%, both got an A and were hired.

That is, of course, the same as Multiplying (.70)(.85).